# How to see if a string is written in a specific form

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to write this code, where a program takes the input in the form: `(x - / + y)(x  / + y)`

I've come this far (ignore the prints as it's written in swedish):

```
user_input = list(input('Skriv ett tal på formen (x +/- y)(x +/- y): '))
operator_list = []


for i in range(len(user_input)):
    if user_input[i] == '-' or user_input[i] == '+':
        operator_list.append(i)

def method():
    if user_input[operator_list[0]] == '-' and user_input[operator_list[1]] == '-':
        return('2:a kvadreringsregeln')

    elif user_input[operator_list[0]] == '+' and user_input[operator_list[1]] == '+':
        return('1:a kvadreringsregeln')

    elif user_input[operator_list[0]] != user_input[operator_list[1]]:
        return('Konjugatregeln')

print('Ditt tal:', ''.join(user_input), 'är skriven enligt:', method())
```

However right now the program doesn't require the user to input it with any parenthesis, or in any particular order,

i.e the input can be:

```
(-- or (          -a)(+
```

etc.

However I want to user to only be able to input the code in this form:

```
(x -/+ y)(x -/+ y) or (x-/+y)(x-/+y) or (x -/+y)( x -/+y)
```

With spaces being of no importance

I was thinking of using the python import regex but I don't know how it works so help would be appreciated :D

Comment: does x and y represents int?

Comment: If you know the form of your statement will be limited to the one quoted above, then regex would be appropriate and the solution to your problem would be to look for a tutorial on regex. Otherwise, what you want is to implement a lexical parser.

Comment: Proper Swedish would have "*i* formen" and neuter *"skrivet"*.

Comment: Cyrex, yeah x and y, could represent both integers and variables, i.e it could be written on the form (43x - 23y)(43x - 23y), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, regex is the right idea. You basically want to write a regular expression that will only match the text you consider "good".

To give a very quick overview of regex, if you write `r"\d+[A-Z][a-z]*"` that would only match strings that start with one or more digits `\d+`, followed by an uppercase letter `[A-Z]`, followed by a lowercase letter `[a-z]`, and ending with whatever `*`.

Your use case sounds complicated, but let me try:

```
import re
pattern = r'\(\w+[+|-]\w+\)\(\w+[+|-]\w+\)'

def test_match(pattern):
    
    assert re.match(pattern, '(x+y)(x+y)')
    assert re.match(pattern, '(x+y)(x-y)')
    assert re.match(pattern, '(x-y)(x+y)')
    assert re.match(pattern, '(x-y)(x-y)')
    assert re.match(pattern, '(a-b)(c-d)')

    assert not re.match(pattern, '(x?y)(x-y)')
    assert not re.match(pattern, '(x-y(x-y)')
    assert not re.match(pattern, '(x-y)(x--y)')

test_match(pattern)
```

And then you could validate your input by doing

```
if re.match(pattern, input_text.replace(' ',''):
   ...
```

Do you need `x` & `y` to be the only valid inputs for the variables?

Comment: Yeah, the quadration forumulas (kvadrerignsreglerna, ((couldn't find an english translation)), requires the two inputs x & y to be the only inputs, thanks for the help I will try your option! :)

Comment: consider `r'\(x[+|-]y\)\(x[+|-]y\)'` This will only allow the characters `x` & `y` as variable names

Answer (score 0):

You can do a Regex with `re` package with the `match` function :

```
import re

input = "(x  +/-y)(x+/-y )"
pattern = "\(x\+/-y\)\(x\+/-y\)"

if re.match(pattern, input.lstrip()) is not None:
    print("your input is on the correct format")
else:
    print("your input is not correct")
```

Note that the `\` character escape special characters (like "()" or "+", ect...). Also, the `.lstrip()` function removes all white space in your string.

Here, the pattern match `x` and `y` as characters, but if you want to check them as integer, your pattern would look like this : `"\(\d+\+/-\d+\)\(\d+\+/-\d+\)"`.

The `\d+` check if the string contains 1 or more digits (between 0 and 9).

For more information about Regex in Python, you can have a look at the [w3school website](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp).

**EDIT :**

If you want to include variable like 43x, 4y... you can do that with the following pattern : `"\(\d+\D*\+/-\d+\D*\)\(\d+\D*\+/-\d+\D*\)"` with `\D*` zero or more string that DOES NOT contain digits.